# Adding Custom Woocommerce Product Type Cannot find WC_Product class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a new custom product type to woo but i keep running into issues.  According to the documentation you need to extend your product class with `WC_Product` or one of the other classes.  But every time I do that, I get an error that says it cannot find `WC_Product` class.

This class is being initialized via a plugin on the following lines

```
$cc_product_type_drawer_box = CabinetCommerce_WC_Product_Type_Drawer_Box::instance();
            add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 
$cc_product_type_drawer_box, 'custom_product_filters' ) );
```

Here's a google drive link to the class file that contains everything except the initializer. 
`https://drive.google.com/open?id=18xZvlQWGksU857DsAJSHar2xWjDgI4aF`

Do i need to load `WC_Product` before I initialize my class or is it being initialized too late?  I'm not quite sure whats wrong.

When I remove the `extends WC_Product` directive everything shows just fine, but then throws an error on save because it can't find some of the functions that are part of `WC_Product`

Comment: I  assume you are running your code before woocommerce loads the class. Can you update your question with all the code you use?

Comment: And you should probably execute this code on unit rather than plugins_loaded

Comment: The code posted is everything.  I tried running on init as well with the same result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the object is being initialized too early, before WC_Product class has been declared.

Try executing your code inside the 'init' hook as follows:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    $cc_product_type_drawer_box = CabinetCommerce_WC_Product_Type_Drawer_Box::instance();
    $cc_product_type_drawer_box->custom_product_filters();
}
```

This way you ensure the class WC_Product has been declared, and as such can be extended. It seems you tried this approach with the 'plugins_loaded' hook, but the implementation wasn't just done properly.